# Custom hit template with Algolia in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, algolia

When installing the Algolia plugin in Shopify, they add a file algolia_instant_search.js.liquid and in that file, there is a code part;

```
  // Hits


instant.search.addWidgets([
    hits({
      container: '.ais-hits-container',
      templates: {
        empty: instant.templates.empty,
        item: instant.templates.product,
      },
      cssClasses: {
        list: 'row',
        item: 'col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-45'
      },
      transformItems: function(products) {
        return products.map(function(product) {
          return algolia.assign({}, product, {
            _distinct: instant.distinct,
            can_order:
              product.inventory_management !== 'shopify' ||
              product.inventory_policy === 'continue' ||
              product.inventory_quantity > 0,
            translations: algolia.translations,
            queryID: product.__queryID,
            productPosition: product.__position,
            index: instant.search.mainIndex.getIndexName(),
          });
        });
      },
    }),
  ]);
```

I want to change the hit template so normally I will add some HTML like this;

```
// Hits
  instant.search.addWidgets([
    hits({
      container: '.ais-hits-container',
      templates: {
        empty: instant.templates.empty,
        item: `
    <div class="single-product">
        <div class="single-product__image"><!-- Product Image Lazyload with Retina  -->
          <a class="image-wrap" href="/collections/all/products/grey-tool">
              <img class="responsive-image__image popup_cart_image" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0559/2632/5423/products/2_540x.jpg?v=1617194828">
          </a>
          <div class="single-product__floating-badges">
              <span class="soldout-title">Soldout</span>
          </div>
          <div class="single-product__content ">
            <div class="title"><h3 class="popup_cart_title">  <a href="/collections/all/products/grey-tool">1. Side Ottoman</a></h3>
                <div class="product-cart-action">
                  <button class="cart-disable">
                    <span class="cart-text">Soldout</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="price">
            <span id="product_current_price" class="discounted-price">€110,00</span>
            <span class="main-price discounted ">€130,00</span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
`,
      },
      cssClasses: {
        list: 'row',
        item: 'col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-45'
      },
      transformItems: function(products) {
        return products.map(function(product) {
          return algolia.assign({}, product, {
            _distinct: instant.distinct,
            can_order:
              product.inventory_management !== 'shopify' ||
              product.inventory_policy === 'continue' ||
              product.inventory_quantity > 0,
            translations: algolia.translations,
            queryID: product.__queryID,
            productPosition: product.__position,
            index: instant.search.mainIndex.getIndexName(),
          });
        });
      },
    }),
  ]);
```

But because it is a .liquid file I can't add the Algolia JS tags like {{ product_image }}, any help on how to do this, and maybe some can tell me where I can find the template the originally put in with `instant.templates.product`

Comment: have you found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You're using tics (`) for your HTML. Have you tried it with single quotes (') instead?